# insert multiple selected value into table (oracle)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

this is my **index.jsp** page

```
<form action="addCountry.jsp" method="get">
    <select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries">
      <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
      <option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
      <option value="AND">Andorra</option>
      <option value="ARG">Argentina</option>
      <option value="ARM">Armenia</option>
      <option value="ABW">Aruba</option>
      <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
      <option value="AUT" selected="selected">Austria</option>
      <option value="AZE">Azerbaijan</option>
      <option value="BGD">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="BLR">Belarus</option>
      <option value="BEL">Belgium</option>
      <option value="BIH">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
      <option value="BRA">Brazil</option>
      <option value="BRN">Brunei</option>
      <option value="BGR">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
      <option value="CHN">China</option>
      <option value="COL">Colombia</option>
      <option value="HRV">Croatia</option>
      <option value="CYP">Cyprus</option>
      <option value="CZE">Czech Republic</option>
</select>
<br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>
```

this would be my **addCountry.jsp** page code

```
<% 
try{
String[] country=request.getParameterValues("countries");
int count=0;
while(country[count]!=null)
out.println(country[count++]);
}catch(Exception ex)
{
//out.print(ex);
}
%>
```

But, i'm very confuse to insert the multiple values into table at the same time. Should i use loop for multiple insertion?? Any help appreciated !! Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why would you put your business logic (much less DB management) in a JSP?

Comment: it's just the sample code, i'll correct it.

Comment: @deporter my question is, after selecting multiple values from the select list, how to insert those values into table, should i use insert query inside loop or there is any other method to insert multiple rows. The code of index.jsp is sample one, i'll retrieve the value from database.

Comment: I'm with @Viruzzo on this one. I have a lovely table, that has all this information in ( plus the proper name ) etc. What's wrong with using the database?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) for `java.sql.Statement` specifically `addBatch(String sql)` and `executeBatch()` methods to queue statements and execute them later together.

Answer (score 0):

```
addCountries(request.getParameterValues("countries"));
```

The following method starts a transaction, performs the queries one at a time, commits if they were all successful and rolls back if there was any error.

```
private void addCountries(String[] countries)
{
    Connection cn = <YOUR_CONNECTION_HERE>;

    try
    {
        // Require Explicit Commit
        cn.setAutoCommit(false);

        // Construct Query
        String  sql = "insert into countries " 
                + "  (country_code) " 
                + "values " 
                + "  (?) ";

        // For each country
        for(String country:countries)
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, country);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
        }

        // Explicitly Commit - This point reached with no Exceptions.
        cn.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Explicitly Rollback - There were errors along the way
        cn.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(cn != null)
        {
            cn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It is bad custom to catch Exception, so I'd recommend changing that part to catch whatever individual exception types are thrown, probably SQLException among others.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide a more detailed solution.

Comment: @sql_query If this the type of solution you're looking for?

Comment: @sql_query Please clarify the question or select the answer that worked for you.

Comment: @sql_query It looks like this question is going to be left as if it was not answered. It would be courteous of you to either select the answer that worked for you or to add the appropriate answer if it was not provided.